# Unable to run helm --set command in bash pipeline when using semicolon

Tags: azure-pipelines, helm, bash

I have a CICD pipeline in yaml which runs a bash command to run a series of helm commands.

Part of the process is to insert values in the pipeline into the container which is installed by helm chart via an environment variable.

However, one of the values for this variable contains : characters. Its essentially a date format, see below.

```
                    echo "Login to Azure"
                    az login --service-principal --username $AZSERVICEPRINCIPAL --password $AZSERVICEPRINCIPALSECRET --tenant $AZTENANTID

                    echo "Obtain AKS Credentials"
                    sudo az aks install-cli
                    az aks get-credentials \
                            -n $(Azure.KubernetesCluster) \
                            -g $(Azure.ResourceGroup) --overwrite-existing --admin

                    echo "Log Helm into ACR"
                    helm registry login $(Azure.AcrName).azurecr.io \
                    --username $ACRUSERNAME \
                    --password $ACRPASSWORD

                    echo "Pull image and unpack"
                    helm pull oci://$(Azure.AcrName).azurecr.io/helm/my-application --version $(tag) --destination $(build.stagingdirectory) --untar
                    ls $(build.stagingdirectory)/my-application

                    echo "Perform Helm Upgrade"
                    helm upgrade my-application $(build.stagingdirectory)/my-application/ --install --debug \
                    --set SharedSendGridEnvironment.SENDGRID_DATE_FORMAT=$SENDGRID_DATE_FORMAT

                    echo "Show results of deployment"
                    helm get all my-application
                    helm status my-application
                  env:
                    ACRUSERNAME: $(env-acr-qa-username)
                    ACRPASSWORD: $(env-acr-qa-password)
                    AZTENANTID: $(env-ecom-tenantid)
                    AZSERVICEPRINCIPAL: $(env-ecom-serviceprincipal)
                    AZSERVICEPRINCIPALSECRET: $(env-ecom-serviceprincipal-secret)
                    SENDGRID_DATE_FORMAT: 'MMMM DD, YYYY h:mm:ss A'
```

If I try to inject the --set command without wrapping it in quotes I receive the error:

```
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
helm.go:84: [debug] "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments
```

Having looked for as solution I tried to combat this I have tried to wrap the set command in quotes like this:

```
--set "SharedSendGridEnvironment.SENDGRID_DATE_FORMAT=$SENDGRID_DATE_FORMAT"
```

Which resolve the issue with the first error but now I get this:

```
Error: failed parsing --set data: key " YYYY h:mm:ss A" has no value
helm.go:84: [debug] key " YYYY h:mm:ss A" has no value
```

So it appears to be confusing the : characters as a key/value initiator.

I have since tried:

1. Removing the quotes, adding the value directly into the script and escaping with double quotes (gives first error)
2. Add double quotes again, adding the value directly into the script (gives the second error)
3. Removed the quotes, added single quotes around the value, escaping with single backslashes (get the first error)
4. Removed the quotes, added double quotes around the value and escaped using double backslahes (gives the second error)

So at this point I am at a loss what else to try.

Can someone please explain how this can be done?